# Fetch Event on document

Tags: javascript, events, fetch

I can't find the way to monitor fetch events globally on document.

In jQuery it was simple:

```
var loading = $('#loading'); //my progress bar
$(document).bind("ajaxSend", function() {
    loading.show();
}).bind("ajaxComplete", function() {
    loading.hide();
}).bind("ajaxSuccess", function() {
    loading.hide();
}).bind("ajaxError", function() {
    loading.hide();
});
```

But when I started using fetch API, I lost this functionality.

Which event must I listen to in order to show the loading bar before fetch and hide it after fetch? Also, I want to do this globally on document. I do NOT want to write it like:

```
loading.show();
fetch('...')
   .then(response => response.json())
   .then(answer => { 
        loading.hide()
   }
.....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can readily get it back:

```
const myFetch = (...args) => {
    loading.show();
    return fetch(...args)
        .then(result => {
            loading.hide();
            return result;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            loading.hide();
            throw error;
        });
};
```

Then call `myFetch` instead of calling `fetch` directly.

Or if you can assume `finally` exists on your platform (or polyfill it):

```
const myFetch = (...args) => {
    loading.show();
    return fetch(...args).finally(() => { loading.hide(); });
};
```

Note that the [`finally` feature](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-promise-finally) is complete will be in the ES2018 spec.

You can even wrap `fetch` if you want to, but I don't recommend it:

```
var originalFetch = fetch;
fetch = /*...one of the above, but using `originalFetch` instead of `fetch`...*/
```

---

Your code doesn't use any ES2015+ features, so those code blocks in ES5:

```
function myFetch() {
    loading.show();
    return fetch.apply(null, arguments)
        .then(function(result) {
            loading.hide();
            return result;
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            loading.hide();
            throw error;
        });
}
```

or

```
function myFetch() {
    loading.show();
    return fetch.apply(null, arguments).finally(function() { loading.hide(); });
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I got it! Choose the first variant. It works, but I also have a question, is it really no any event on document to monitor fetch like it do jquery with its ajax requests?

Comment: @VladimirMedinsky: I don't see one in the spec: https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#fetch-method This is just like `XMLHttpRequest`, which also doesn't offer any global events. jQuery's add-on features are add-on features. :-)